# Webflux only allowing 6 connections for the api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

While making the following call http://localhost:8080/test for the the TestController I was not able to get more the 6 responses from the server in parallel. The requests just keep waiting for the request I made before to finish. Is there a way to increase this number per API(Controller)?

**TestController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class TestController() {


    @GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
    fun test(): Flux<String> {
        return Flux
                .interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .map { t ->  "test $t"}

    }
}
```

*Number of CPUs in the machine running the application:* 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling your server from an internet browser. Max 6 connections to a domain is a known [browser limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser). HTTP/2 or WebSocket can offer a solution.

Comment: Oh my god I forgot about this one! One more thing I want to point it out is,  because Chrome, Opera and Edge use the same engine I had to use Firefox in order to get more connections in the same computer.